# Is there any difference between these two wordings of a probability question?

Tags: probability

Are the following two questions the same and do they have the same answer?  EDIT: in both cases there's no interaction between apples, they go bad independently

1) 1% of all apples are bad.  Apples come in crates of 100.  Today I will open a crate.  What are the chances that there are no bad apples in it?

2) Apples come in crates of 100.  Having opened many crates, the average number of bad apples I have encountered in a crate is 1.  Today I will open a crate.  What are the chances that there are no bad apples in it?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from one probability being exact, and the other empirical (and therefore not entirely certain), the two descriptions are equivalent.

Note that you still can't solve the problem as you for instance have no idea whether apples tend to rot together (maybe only one in 100 barrels have rotten apples, but in those barrels all apples are rotten, or every barrel has exactly one rotten apple).

Comment: I edited to add a comment to say that apples go bad independently

Comment: Is the answer to both 0.99^100 in your opinion?

Comment: If the apples rot independently, then yes, that seems right.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I thought.  The original asker of version 2 intended the answer to come from Poisson distribution analysis of it

Comment: Also, apples in the real world are well-known to rot together (as illustrated by the idiom "one bad apple spoils the barrel").

Comment: @HeadScratcher: The asker of version 2 is simply wrong. The poisson distribution only arises if the number of apples in each crate goes to $\infty$ and yet the expected number of bad apples in each crate is a constant.